# Changing Jquery key binding for Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a modal dialog. I need to close the dialog on a different key combination than the Easape key. How can I do that.

I have the following code, but that never is executed. Any clues why ?

```
var agreeDialog = $j('#termsOfAgreementConfirm').dialog({
            modal: true,
            autoOpen:false,
            resizable:false,
            width : 1000,
            height :400,
            stack:false,
            title:"Terms of Usage",
              open: function(event, ui) { $j('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide(); },
            buttons: {

                Disagree: function() {
                    disagree.dialog('open');
                    disagree.dialog('moveToTop');

                },
                Agree: function() {
                    $j(this).dialog('close');
                    $j.cookie("agree","Y");
                    new Ajax.Request('/test/user/ajaxUpdateAgreementForUser',
                            {
                                onSuccess:function(resp){
                                },
                                onError: function(resp) {
                                    alert("Error:" + resp.toJSON());
                                    return;
                                },
                                asynchronous:true,
                                evalScripts:true
                           });
                    $j(this).dialog('close');

                }
            }
        });
        if (result == "false" && $j.cookie("agree")== null) {
           agreeDialog.dialog('open')
           agreeDialog.keyup(function e() {
                alert(e.keyCode);
           });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to catch the key events on the body and then trigger the close event. See this exmaple. Pressing any key will close the dialog box. You have to do it outside your declaration.

http://jsfiddle.net/yu8Sg/

```
$('body').keyup( function(e) {    
    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: I had tried this before but I wasn't seeing expected results. Now it worked.